# Help identify this part - possibly train related?

Tags: part-identification

I suspect it might be related to a train coupler but I could be totally wrong. I couldn't find it in the train parts category on Bricklink. It seems similar to [part 2920](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2920&name=Train%20Coupling&category=%5BTrain%5D#T=C&C=11).

It has an open stud on the top and an antistud on the bottom, and a regular axle hole going across. The clip things that are on one side are smaller than the diameter of a regular bar.

It says "(C) Lego Group" and "3" and "01" but I do not see a part number.

[image: the piece in question - diagonal view]
[image: the piece in question - top view]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the Magnet category: [2607](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2607) Magnet Holder 2 x 3 with Clips and Pin Hole. It connects to [Magnet Cylindrical](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1603).

[image: Magnet Cylindrical]

Comment: These were used heavily in the 90s with their underwater line and I think some of the digger line.

Comment: They were also the key naming item in the M-Tron space sets.